# Display UIImageView in full screen (320*480)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I know there are some questions about UIImageView full-size have been asked but I'm still stuck with my problems.

I have a navigation bar, a scrollview, a UIImageView (named avatarTest) and a button. When I press the image, the UIImageView expand to full-size (320*480) and set the avatarTest.contentMode is ModeCenter.

My problems are:

- UIImageView expanded to 320*480 but it didn't replace the navigation bar and status bar (like picture 1 and 2)
- When I scroll down (now my button appear) and I press image, the UIImageView still expand according the old view. I want it expand to the full size, fill my current view (window) (like picture 3 and 4)
- I want to know how to determine the origin frame (CGRectMake) of UIImageView by code so I can code for the 2nd press action (resize the image to origin)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are some my viewController.m codes:

```
- (IBAction) expand {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;            
        avatarTest.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        avatarTest.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
        avatarTest.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    }]; 
}
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense. How is picture 3 or 4 full size? What is the "old view"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, you have to make sure your frames are correct. I notice that you are keeping the x and y of the origin, maybe these have to be reset each time. Some experimentation will soon lead to the desired result.

**Second**, by setting the `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeCenter` you are preventing the image from being scaled. You need to enable a content mode that scales the image like one of these:

```
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
```

**Finally**, to cover the navigation bar, you will have to *remove* the view from the main view and *add it to the window* instead.

```
[avatarTest removeFromSuperview]; 
[self.view.window addSubview:avatarTest];
```

Of course to reset you will have to do the opposite.
Also, I recommend to clean this up in `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it successfully. But I still don't know how to determine the x, y, width, height of my origin frame to make it back from the beginning. Actually I have to check the x, y... in the Storyboard to know. Thank you in advance. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the status bar and the navigation bar you have to hide them.  To hide them without animation...

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

And of course when you want them back you'll have to set hidden to NO.